# log4net in vb.net not logging in database table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, log4net

I am working on an upgrade in vb.net website application (not web application) to add logging of errors and messages to a database log table. I had gone through couple of sites and answers to achieve logging to database using Log4Net. Below are the code set up.

**web.config** added the `<config>` and `<log4net>` sections

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>  
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />

  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="GeneralLogger">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="GeneralAppender" />
    </logger>
    <appender name="GeneralAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, 
   System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=[MyDataSource];Initial Catalog=[MyDB];Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO ErrorLog ([Error Description],Date) VALUES (@logDesc, getdate())" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logDesc" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <conversionPattern value="%logDesc" />
      </parameter>

    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <connectionStrings>......
```

A sample page **LogTester.aspx.vb**

```
Imports log4net


Partial Class LogTester
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        log.Error("Test error")
    End Sub End Class
```

I had added the **log4net.dll** as reference that I took from another c# project to the website. When I run the application no errors are shown but nothing is getting logged in the db table.

Please help me with anything that I am missing.

**[UPDATE]**: When debugging I found the `log` variable does not take any appenders. When digging deeper with quickwatch the appender count is 0. The appender part contains the details of database and insert query.

**[UPDATE 2]**: I changed the code

> `Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog =
>   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)`

to

> `Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog =
>   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("GetLogger")`

Comment: is your debugg firing to that method?

Comment: Yes it is. It goes past the method call without errors but nothing gets logged.

Comment: just to confirm in your `Application_Start` in did you configure your log4net like this `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

Comment: I just gave it now but still no rows in table

Comment: just try to log it to the file initially without  DB so that we are making sure `log4net` is working, then we can check with DB inserting

Comment: I made a small change. Instead of 'log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)' I gave 'log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("GeneralLogger")' The code was then considering the appender section. But still I could not log it to database nor to file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144238/discussion-between-webruster-and-nisha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to  Change your Pattern Layout from

```
<conversionPattern value="%logDesc" />
```

to

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"> 
<conversionPattern value="%logDesc"/> 
</layout>
```